# WriteFileSync doesn't create a file but also doesn't cause an error

Tags: node.js

```
if (url === '/message' && method === 'POST') {
    const body = [];
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        const message = parsedBody.split('=')[1];
        fs.writeFileSync('message.txt', message);
    });
    res.statusCode = 302;
    res.setHeader('Location', '/');
    return res.end();   
}
```

This part seems to not create a file, but also oesn't cause error to occur. Anyone had similar issues?

Comment: Your two events for data and end are on res, but should they be req?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.